# Listbox Laravel data

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im trying to retrieve data from my database to my listbox 
 but it's not working this my html code

```
 <select style="width:90%"class="form-control">

          @foreach($clients as $client)
          <center><option name="client_id" value= {{ $client->id}} >{{ $client->num_mowakil }} | {{$client->nom_mowakil}}</option></center>
          @endforeach
        </select>
```

My problem is with the value I get the error:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'client_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sujets
```

And this is my function in the controller to save it I think the problem is from the html code:

```
public function store(Request $request){
     $sujet = new Sujet;
      $sujet->client_id=$request->input('client_id');
      $sujet->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "name" attribute must go on the `select` statement, not on the `option` ones.

For instance:

```
 <select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```